# Entity Framework Code First Migration Class didn't work

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm building an application using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework  I've recently learned about EF Code-First Migrations tool you can implement on your application for your database. I ran "Enable-Migration" in the PM Console, and it enabled successfully and created the "InitialModel.cs" class as expected with the appropriate up() and down() methods filled in with the table creations.

Then I went ahead and added another class (Attendance.cs) with some simple properties (GigId, AttendanceId) and wanted to add this migration to the database. I ran "Add-Migration Attandences" in my PM to get this message:

and it display.

The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your current Code
First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the changes to your model when you    scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to    include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it

i have find a similar problem which i followed and i also tried to  AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; and then add-migration but it didn't work.
I have deleted the  __MigrationHistory table from database and now when i tried to run Enable-Migration it give me folowing error.

More than one context type was found in the assembly 'test'.
To enable migrations for 'test.ApplicationDbContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName test.ApplicationDbContext.
To enable migrations for 'test.Models.ApplicationDbContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName test.Models.ApplicationDbContext.
        }

```
public class Attendances
{
    public Gig Gig { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Attendee { get; set; }


    [Key]
    [Column(Order =1)]
    public int GigId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string AttendanceId { get; set; }
}



public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Gig> Gigs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Attendances> Attendance { get; set; }


    public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

More than one context type was found in the assembly 'test'.
To enable migrations for 'test.ApplicationDbContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName test.ApplicationDbContext.
To enable migrations for 'test.Models.ApplicationDbContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName test.Models.ApplicationDbContext.